# Problem using WiiGee?

Tags: java, wiimote

Has anyone tried [Wiigee](http://wiigee.org)? I am planning to use it but I am facing a problem related to bluetooth (I am using BlueCove (latest version)). Whenever I try to compile and run the demo program (which is downloaded from Wiigee site) my wiimote is not detected by BlueCove. I played a lot with wiimote but it's the first time I have tried to connect to it in java.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: WiiGee URL:  http://www.wiigee.org/

Answer (score 0):

Have you synced the Wiimote with the compter? To do this, either

1. Hold down the '1' and '2' buttons down simultaneously
2. Open the battery cover, and press the red "SYNC" button.

The Wiimote should appear as Nintendo "RVT-CNT-01".

Comment: Bluetooth pairing happens in the OS, not in the WiiGee layer.

Comment: But he said BlueCove isn't recognising it.. I assume that's some kind of Bluetooth stack/manager?

Comment: Thanks alot everyone for your reply. Actually i am agree with person-b that i have problem with blueCove. My wiimote is syn as it appears RVT-CNT-01.

Comment: If this solved your problem, then accept the answer (the tick), or if you solved it yourself, if you can, post instructions in a new answer and accept that. Thanks!